# Large font sizes not displaying on Android 3.0 tablet

Tags: android

In a Textview with

```
<TextView
    android:text="12.3c"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

When I set the text size to 200 dp, only the dot in the middle is displayed; for smaller sizes I get . c without the digits; if I bring it right down I get 12.3c

Is there an upper limit on font size? (I am using droid Sans)

Thanks

Comment: In which way do you set text size?

Comment: could it be a screen support thing? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Comment: At 100dp I get the full string; at 120dp I get . c

Comment: Also tried
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:textSize="200dp"

same result: just the dot.